# Make a GET request to Yesmail using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, get-request

I'm trying to make a GET request to the Yesmail API and return the data associated to a email marketing campaign based on a message ID that right now is hard coded but would eventually be passed. Right now I keep getting a 401 (Unauthenticated). I have been using the "[Sample Request Header](https://developer.yesmail.com/sample-request-header)" but I'm still missing something. Am I structuring the headers correctly? Am I passing the correct parameters at all?

```
function doFetch(ev) {
  // this needs to be HTTPS
  let uri = 'https://api.test.yesmail.com/v2/reports/master-events/message_id_here';

  let h = new Headers();
  let encoded = window.btoa('my_key_here');
  h.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  h.append('Api-key', 'encoded');
  h.append('Api-User', 'my_username_here');
  h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  h.append('Connection', 'keep-alive');

  let req = new Request(uri, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: h,
    mode: 'cors'
  });
  // credentials: 'include' means a different domain.
  // credentials: 'same-origin' means the same domain.

  fetch(req)
  .then( (response)=>{
      if(response.ok){
          return response.json();
      }else{
          throw new Error('BAD HTTP stuff');
      }
  })
  .then( (jsonData) =>{
      console.log(jsonData);
      p.textContent = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4);
  })
  .catch( (err) =>{
      console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
  });
}
```

Comment: I would omit the `Connection: keep-alive` header as it's not in their `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` list

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo in your question but it should be `h.append('Api-Key', encoded)` (ie, no quotes around `encoded`)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change 'Api-key' to 'Api-Key' in your header?

Comment: @ErikB the HTTP spec says header names should be treated case-insensitively. They'd have to be using a weird request processing library to not handle that correctly. Worth a shot though, that's why I changed it in my comment above :)

Comment: I tried all of these things and now its saying `Failed to load https://api.test.yesmail.com/v2/reports/master-events/1160828: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:52698' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` in the console.